# OAuth 2.0 how to encrypt client id and secret

Tags: oauth-2.0

When requesting access to an application via OAuth 2.0 you need certain credentials. In the case of google the request URL which sends the user to a page to allow access contains the client ID and Secret. Does this not leave the data open for anyone to grab request access to apps on my applications behalf?

Also, is OAuth only possible through a browser or can it be achieved completely server side?

I'm pretty new to this so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Your calls to the OAuth 2.0 authorization server which contain your client ID and client secret MUST be made over an encrypted channel (= using SSL/TLS). The [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1) says (chapter 2.3.1):

```
 The authorization server MUST require the use of TLS as described in Section 1.6 when sending requests using password authentication.
```